Azure Databricks - Error message: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Missing cloud file system scheme
I'm trying to run a Datafactory pipeline that has a Databricks notebook that creates a table. However, it always generates the error:

The same if I try manually:

I've tried using prefix: 'dbfs:' and 'wasbs:'. But it ended up giving another error.
However, when I run ls, it works:

How to solve this?

When using Mount Points in HMS you dont have to mention wasbs protocol. The folder can be referred to as /mnt/mount_name
Unity Catalog doesn't support wasbs ://
Please create a container under abfss:// and copy the files from wasbs:// and add it to External Locations under your metastore.
